# Stuck trying to insert data into mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a contact list on my mySQL database. The columns on my database are name, email and phone_number. Using codeigniter. I know the code I need to insert the data from the form into the database but I can't figure out where to put it into the code. I had the code below in a separate document called form.php but that just kept giving me errors anytime I hit submit. Hence why form.php is in the view.php form.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone_number'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO data (name, email, phone_number) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone')";
```

controller.php:

```
<?php

class controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('model');
        $data['info'] = $this->model->getData();

        $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }

}
?>
```

model.php:

```
<?php

    class model extends CI_Model
{

    public function getData()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('data');

        return $query->result();
    }
}
?>
```

view.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact List</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_number"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="history.go(0)" value="Refresh">
</form>
<br>
<?php
    foreach ($records as $rec) {
        echo "Name: ".$rec->name."<br>";
        echo "Email: ".$rec->email."<br>";
        echo "Phone Number:".$rec->phone_number."<br><br>";
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is bad understanding of MVC arhitecture. If you are new, take time and explore it.

-View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact List</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo form_open('controller/insert');?>
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_number"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="history.go(0)" value="Refresh">
<?php echo form_close();?>
<br>
<?php
    foreach ($info as $rec) {
        echo "Name: ".$rec->name."<br>";
        echo "Email: ".$rec->email."<br>";
        echo "Phone Number:".$rec->phone_number."<br><br>";
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

CONTROLLER

```
<?php

class controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __CONSTRUCT(){
            parent::_CONSTRUCT();
            $this->load->helper('file');
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('model');

        }
        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('model');
            $data['info'] = $this->model->getData();

            $this->load->view('view', $data);
        }

        public function insert() {

            $data = array (
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'phone_number' => $this->input->post('phone_number')
                );

            $this->model->insert_data($data);
            $this->load->view('view');

        }

    }
    ?>
```

MODEL

```
<?php

    class model extends CI_Model
{
    function __CONSTRUCT(){
        parent::__CONSTRUCT();
        $this->load->database('your_databse_name');
        $this->load->library('db'); // optionali you could set it on autoload 

    }

    public function getData()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('data');

        return $query->result();
    }

    public function insert_data($data){
        $this->db->insert('your_data_table', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

I think this should help you.

Comment: I ran your code and i get an error " Unable to load the requested class: Db", If I comment that out the code works for the most part but when I hit submit I get two errors, 1) Undefined variable: info 2) invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Both are in view.php

Comment: Oh, sorry! Delete line $this->load->library("db");Errors in your view exist because name of variable inside of your foreach statement is not same as name of $data variable in controller which is passed to view. To be clear, in controller variable $data['info'] = $this->model->getData(); and argument in view inside foreach statement should be like this:  foreach ($info as $rec), i think this should work, but however check your code.

Comment: Checked the code as I have what you posted in your last comment, so still unsure what is causing the errors. This is what is showing below the errors Backtrace:

File: E:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\Contact\application\views\view.php
Line: 22
Function: _error_handler

File: E:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\Contact\application\controllers\controller.php
Line: 36
Function: view

File: E:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\Contact\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Side question the refresh button I have isn't reloading to the original page could this be because of the errors.

Comment: Here is official Codeigniter user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/  and video tuts from Envato https://code.tutsplus.com/categories/codeigniter, and this video is about basic CRUD operations of Codeigniter and database https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvVsYVW4FmA

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to submit a form. But you're submitting it to `form.php` which does not exist.

To elaborate further: In traditional PHP you would submit your form to a new page or the same page and check for $_POST values in that page. Since Codigniter is an MVC framework, you would post your data back to a controller. Which controller doesn't matter.

In your controller you load a model where you create a function to write or get data from or to the database. However, the model is less used nowadays. I'm not sure why because it keeps things organized.

After the controller has processed the data, a new view is loaded. In your case you would create a new view named form.php and load the view via the controller method.

The correct way to do this would be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact List</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="controller/form" method="post">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_number"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="history.go(0)" value="Refresh">
</form>
<br>
<?php
    foreach ($records as $rec) {
        echo "Name: ".$rec->name."<br>";
        echo "Email: ".$rec->email."<br>";
        echo "Phone Number:".$rec->phone_number."<br><br>";
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Your controller should like this:

```
<?php

class controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('model');
        $data['info'] = $this->model->getData();

        $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }
    public function form() {
        $this->load->model('model');
        $data = array(
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'phone_number' => $_POST['phone_number'] // should be exact table column name for this to work
        );
        $this->model->insertData($data);
        $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

And in your model:

```
<?php

class model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getData()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('data');

        return $query->result();
    }
    public function insertData($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('data', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

**After you copied my answer, you supplied invalid argument into foreach statement.

Should be:

```
foreach ($info as $rec) {
```

Instead of yours

```
foreach ($records as $rec) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Create method in model *public function insert($data)*

```
public function insert($data){
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (name, email, phone_number) VALUES ('$data['name']', '$data['email']', '$data['phone_number']')";

$this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: so in the view.php do I have action="model.php" where action="form.php" is currently?

Comment: I'm getting this error.
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: In your action="controller.php"..

Comment: `public function inController(){
$this->model->insert($this->post());
}`

PS: Load Model!!

Comment: im still getting the same error is somewhere on this line: $sql = "INSERT INTO data (name, email, phone_number) VALUES ('$data['name']', '$data['email']', '$data['phone_number']')";

Comment: var_dump($data) before variable $sql and see..